# How to keep my cat stress free during periods of constant 90dB+ sound?

Tags: cats, behavior

In India today and tomorrow is the festival of Diwali. It is the festival of light and banned firecrackers over 90 dB sound are all too common. It can be compared to war zone in Syria with constant sound of high dB bombs.

Now my cat is very afraid because of these sounds. It is quite stressful for my cat. How can I make my cat less stressed?

Comment: Here is a handy table explaining how loud 90db might be: https://www.chem.purdue.edu/chemsafety/Training/PPETrain/dblevels.htm

You may wish to pick something like this and cite the source for a more factual comparison of the volume.

Comment: When I was growing up, we had a dog that didn't like fireworks.  (our central-U.S. neighborhood went nuts during the 4th of July celebration)  So my brother got the idea to put the dog in his room with the big sound system that the dog was already used to, turn it up, and go have fun.  It seemed to work.

Comment: I don't even have a clue how to keey **myself** stress free.  The cat is much smarter than the humans in this case.

Comment: @Henders personally I don’t find any of the examples for 90db helpful in that link. I don’t have any idea how loud a Boeing 737 or DC-9 aircraft at one nautical mile (6080 ft) before landing or Newspaper press is and noise of motor cycles and power mowers can vary widely IME.

Comment: @martin i agree. Far better to get a free spl meter on your phone to estimate the amplitude than to look at a chart of things you've never heard and guess. That would make it FAR less factual, and much more subjective.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm in the UK so our nearest equivalent would be the fireworks displays during Bonfire Night and New Year's Eve so I'll base my answer on what I advise to do during those:

- Keep the cat indoors during hours where the fireworks will be set off
- Keep all windows shut and curtains drawn to try and muffle the noise
- Make sure the cat has easy access to their favorite "hiding" places - and if they go to one of these don't try and remove them as this will freak them out more.
- Be extra vigilant when entering/exiting your home - a cat startled by fireworks may panic and run without considering direction and you don't want them escaping by accident
- Consider using a synthetic pheromone plug-in diffuser such as [Feliway](https://www.feliway.com/uk/Feliway-Range/Feliway-Classic), these work by releasing synthetic versions of the pheromones secreted by mother cats and they have a calming effect on the cat.

Comment: The cat indeed *must* be able to hide.

Comment: Regarding "hiding places", I've heard of people making partially soundproofed boxes for dogs to help with noise-related stress. Might be an idea in the future, if the cat gets used to the box ahead of time.

Comment: One funny story... I adopted a 14 year old cat from one of my tenants who could not take her when she left. It was one of the best things that has ever happened to me. She was afraid of fireworks that happen a couple of time a year. She stopped being afraid and even started watching them out of the window when I showed excitement over the fireworks. I love fireworks and so I shared my enthusiasm. Within one year my cat was not afraid anymore and we enjoyed the fireworks together in the window until she died years later. Being cheerful and positive may really help. Who knows?

Comment: What would catnip do? Would it make it better or worse?

Comment: @corsiKa With no evidence or real idea, I feel like it'd be worse. But then, every cat reacts a bit different to catnip. My cat gets poofytail and runs around like crazy. My friends cat lays down and doesn't move.

Comment: @closetnoc I've heard a lot about the empathy of animals. Usually dogs more, but my cat knows when i'm upset or depressed and will sit with me. Alternatively, if i'm excited and jump around, he'll run around with me and seem excited as well. If YOU (OP) are stressed that the cat will be stressed, then the cat may get stressed from that alone.

Comment: @AytAyt Exactly! My Sassy, before she passed, was great company when I was having a bad day. This was during a period when my Mom's health declined. She was very comforting intentionally. My current kitty is the same way. Cheers!!

Comment: _"synthetic pheromone plug-in diffuser"_ Thank you for that info - I didn't even know vapors with synthetic pheromones exist. And with new years eve around I'll test them on my furry rascals in order to ease their distress a bit including your other advices.

Answer (score 15):

You have to let her be able to hide. Maybe make her a cardboard box and cover this with some thick fabric to dampen the loud noise. Normally cats get over it quite fast after the noises have stopped (at least my cats have calmed down rapidly).

A cat will normally be more scared the first time this happens and it can take some time before she comes out of her hiding place.

Some vets give medication to cats before the noise starts (here it is new years eve). My vet gave me a pill for my cat but this made my cat lose control and made it harder for my cat to cope with the stress. I am not saying your cat will react negatively to medication but mine did.

When the fireworks start my cat hides under my bed and usually comes out about 10 minutes after it have stopped.

The most important thing is for you to stay calm and relaxed and let your cat hide and not force her out of hiding. She will come out from hiding within 1 hour after the noise stops normally.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the type of cat you have the best course of action is to just be in the house and make sure your cat knows you are near(from time to time try caling him/her name), eventualy your cat will come out of hiding and come to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would helpful if you could explain why your solution depends on the type of cat and for which type it can be helpful.

Comment: Depending on species/gender of the cat they react in diferent ways towards danger , some respond more actively(they become agresive) some more pasive(they hide)

Comment: Thank you. Do you have some examples which specie tends to react in which way?

Comment: In my case i have had 2 thai siameses so far(second one stil living) both male and from time to time in my town celebrations fireworks were often used...They usualy run off to hide then come back to sit on your lap ... I can't say much more about other species :( search for yours' personality traits or just wait and see xD hope it helped :)